# Working Directory Different for Different Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, mstest

My team and I are working on an application that is stored in BitBucket with Visual Studio 2015 being our primary IDE. Our application's unit tests fail when the `DataSource` attribute is used, but pass when it is not.

One thing I've noticed is that when the `DataSource` attribute is used, the working directory for the tests (obtained via the `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` property as well as the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase` property) is:

> TestResuts\[generated directory name]\Out

The working directory when there is no `DataSource` is the project's configured output path: 'bin\Debug'. This is why the tests cannot find the `DataSource` files - though they are set to `Copy always` in the file properties, they are being copied to my bin\Debug directory and **not** my TestResults/.../Out directory.

Here's the oddest part - we do not have a Settings file for the project and this just started happening recently. So a new working directory was not configured and we did not change this intentionally.

Why would the DataSource attribute change the executing directory, and not copy over the file indicated in the attribute c'tor?

Is there any other reason you can think of that this may be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Which testing framework? Does it have test isolation settings? Most of the time it is better to mark files to deploy to isolated tests than rely on the working directory. (The Debug folder is primarily for debugging; rather than testing.)

Comment: Ah yes, we're using the built-in Visual Studio Unit Test Project. Nothing too fancy.

Comment: New information discovered, editing question.